# How to stop file paths and info from showing up on python script execution

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So whenever I run python in vsc (python 3.8) it shows the environment, file path, and other stuff (see screenshot) which makes it difficult to look through past console messages. It is like this on the latest stable release, so I uninstalled vsc and all of its associated files, then re-installed the insider edition, but things stayed the same. I have pretty much had to move to a new code editor because of this.

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W648r.png)

Comment: How are you running python? this looks like a run configuration specific issue

Answer (score 0):

If you use `launch.json` configurations to run your code there's no way to truncate the commands. But if you run using the green Play button then it should only use the path to path and the path to the file.